# Adjust color profile on Windows 10

Tags: apps, settings, windows-10-mobile, display, system-apps

Windows Phone 8 and 8.1 had the option to adjust the color temperature and saturation of the display in the display settings, as [explained in this article.](http://ccm.net/faq/35193-windows-phone-8-adjust-the-color-profile-of-your-display) When I updated my old 8.1 device to Windows 10, it retained this option. However, on my new phone with Windows 10 installed by default, there doesn't seem to be an option for this.

I searched the app store for a [f.lux](https://justgetflux.com/)-like app, but sadly there are no apps which can do this. I hoped that [SysApp Pusher](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/sysapp-pusher/9wzdncrfhvls) might let me download the old display settings app, but that also failed.

How can you adjust the color temperature and saturation in Windows 10 Mobile?

Comment: Windows 10 Mobile does consist the Color Profile option. See this article: http://www.windowscentral.com/make-lumia-950-display-vivid

Comment: My phone is missing not just the color profile option but a whole category of settings, see [my other question](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/12651/missing-extras-category-in-settings) if you are having this same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Settings -> Extras -> Screen, then you can select color or brightness profiles.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have an "Extras" category in my settings. What version of Windows are you running? Or maybe it has something to do with my phone being an Alcatel and not Microsoft/Nokia?

Comment: I have the latest Windows 10 release, on a Nokia Lumia 930..
The "Extras" option is at the bottom of the the settings menu

Comment: It's not there for me, sadly. However, this does seem to be the correct answer for the original question so I'm going to accept it and ask a different one regarding my missing settings.

Comment: Yes all such settings are available but it isnt showing any change on lumia 535