# Missing "Extras" category in Settings

Tags: settings, windows-10-mobile, system-apps

On my Alcatel OneTouch Fierce XL with Windows 10, there is no "Extras" category in my settings app. Is this Microsoft/Nokia exclusive? If not, how can I access this part of the settings?

I'm running OS build 10.0.10586.107 and have ensured all of my apps are up to date.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching and reading a few posts about this particular setting, I can say that this feature *is not* a Nokia/Lumia exclusive. 'Extras' contains all the settings/options that are not yet included in the new categorized settings of Windows 10 and as mentioned by @Indrek, also that are specific OEM customization  features. That's why it is not available for your phone.

Refer: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mobiledevices/forum/mdlumia-mdsettings/why-lumia-535-doesnt-have-a-lumia-color-profile/f8ef78bf-1696-4bb7-9761-07443ab48bbb?tab=question&status=AllReplies#tabs

Comment: In other words, that category is *not* a Lumia-exclusive, it's just that Lumia phones are the only ones that take advantage of it?

Comment: Correct. But in the future maybe, Alcatel can also have their exclusive features and they would probably be included in Extras.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, this is not Lumia-exclusive, but is simply designed to contain any manufacturer-specific settings that aren't covered by the built-in categories. For instance, on my Lumia 950 the Extras category contains things like colour profile and Glance screen.

I'm guessing Alcatel phones don't contain any such settings and therefore the Extras category isn't needed.