# What app can bring similar feature as "Night Shift" found in iOS on Windows 10 Mobile?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, apps

There is a feature in iOS called Night Shift to reduce eye strain when viewing my phone at night. It’s also designed to get rid of that bright blue light emitted by my device at night that impacts my sleeping habits. This feature was brought to Android also through many 3rd party apps. Can anyone guide me if there any app in Microsoft Store that would give this feature for free?

For those who don't know what "Night-shift"is? See this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qkybUwthZAs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adjust color profile on Windows 10](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/12634/adjust-color-profile-on-windows-10)

Comment: No @Jake Its not.

Answer (score 2):

In the Extra Settings menu under Settings, you can change color tone and contrast to your likings.

Comment: I'm too lazy to get to it. I want to reach it with just one tap as I control most important settings from the action center or at least with third party app that will make this feature accessible with one tap.

Answer (score 0):

Go to display settings and reduce the brightness to the low option, and when you need to change from low light, just adjust it from action center. Works great for me

Comment: ..then after reducing it to a very low brightness, switch "Automatic Brightness" on

Comment: Lowering screen brightness  does not achieve what I am talking about. See it here in action:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Q3t9DbbPTU